# Call to a member function errorInfo() on string

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm running through a tutorial where it uses MySQLi but instead I'm using PDO and I have been trying to pin the issue to why I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function errorInfo() on string in D:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\repos\bla\web\inboxPage.php on line 34

Here is where I am trying to call the errorInfo(), I had previously used `mysql_error();` as per tutorial, but this also threw the same error. Before using errorInfo() I was looking around to see if there was a PDO equivelant to mysql_error() which lead me to what you see below - Me thinking it would work. But it didn't.

Tutorials example:

```
$query = "SELECT id, sender, subject, message FROM messages WHERE reciever='$user'";
$sqlinbox = mysql_query($query);

if(!$sqlinbox)
    {
    ?>
    <p><?php print '$query: '.$query.mysql_error();?></p>
    <?php
    }
```

My Example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, Sender, Subject, Message FROM privatemessages WHERE Receiver = :receiver';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':receiver', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!$result){
  ?>
  <p><?php print '$sql: '.$sql.errorInfo(); ?></p>
  <?php
}
```

Here is my connection to the database:

```
$servername = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$database = 'tutor_database';

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $user, $pass);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e){
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

In addition, I did try the first example from the PHP Manual website -> http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php and found that doing so gave me:

> PDO::errorInfo():
>   Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\repos\bla\web\inboxPage.php on line 37
>       $sql: Array

...instead.

Would appreciate some help on this as I'm clearly failing to see what is happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Chay22 You need to call it off of the connection not the statement. `$conn->errorInfo();`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have tried both kinds and it just leads me to the second error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PDO a [**completely different** method for the error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) have to be used. In short, PDO will report its errors already, without the need to write any code.

So just take out the error reporting part, leaving only

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, Sender, Subject, Message FROM privatemessages WHERE Receiver = :receiver';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':receiver', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

that's all you need.

Comment: Thank you! This has helped me to move on :)